# NO FBML is working in iframe in facebook using PHP (ie or ff or anywhere else!)

Tags: php, facebook, fbml, xfbml

I have tried for three days now and gotten nowhere on this.... I absolutely can not get any "fb:" code to render anything! I've tried the exact code in the sandbox and it works fine. I've read through every search result I could find and gotten nowhere...

I'm using a standard xd_receiver page, and in the **body** there's this line:

```
< script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here's my index page. It's basically the stock facebook example code....

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook-platform/php/facebook.php';

//Authentication Keys
$appapikey = 'MY_KEY';         // obviously this is my real key
$appsecret = 'MY_SECRET';      // same thing

$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?
   echo "<p>Hello, <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\"></fb:name>!</p>";

?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){
   FB.Facebook.init("<?php echo $appapikey; ?>", "xd_receiver.htm");
  });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

oddly enough, when I put this code below where it echos the logged in user's name, it does show the id numbers of friends. But again, it won't render their names

```
<?php
   friends.get API method echo "<p>Friends:";
   $friends = $facebook->api_client->friends_get();
   $friends = array_slice($friends, 0, 25);
   foreach ($friends as $friend) {
      echo "<br>".$friend." - <fb:name uid=\".$user_id.\" useyou=\"false\"></fb:name>";
   }
   echo "</p>";
?>
```

Here's my settings:

Canvas Callback URL
http://www.my-actual-website.com/test/

Canvas URL
http://apps.facebook.com/gogre_testapp/

FBML/iframe
iframe

Application Type
Website

Post-Remove URL
http://www.my-actual-website.com/test/

Post-Authorize URL
http://www.my-actual-website.com/test/

Please, somebody help me out! I've been trying unsuccessfully for days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XFBML problems are often a result of Facebook being unable to access your xd_receiver.htm file.  Try putting the full URL to `xd_receiver.htm`, ie. `http://yourdomain.com/xd_receiver.htm` in the `FB.Facebook.init` line, and make sure that the file is being served properly by accessing it manually.

The other thing that will definitely cause this is failing to set the **Connect URL** in your app settings.  Go to the Developer app and edit your settings.  Under the Connect options, set the Connect URL to your main site, ie. `http://yourdomain.com/`.

Comment: So the problem could have been either of the things you mentioned, because my Connect URL was blank and my xd_receiver did have that problem... But either way it seems to work. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem.  I know how frustrating FB Connect can be.  Good luck with it.